# Transactional camel queue

Tags: transactions, jms

There are 2 objects in my queue.
I want to get  first object from my queue and process it and if  any error gets,I will put it back and again take and process again.(In process,error throws if 20 secs did not pass after that object putted in queue).

When I start my camel context,it gets first object,process it,throws error.Again takes it,process it,throws error.It works as I want.
 However,at the same time second object from queue has same cycle.I want it to wait  till first object arrives to my end point.

```
from(queueName).errorHandler(defaultErrorHandler()).process(checkTimeInterval()).to("seda:sub");
```

How can I provide to wait second object in queue?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example program that creates a queue and shows the problem that you're having?

Comment: I found the reason that is another consumer from a different interface machine also trying to consume queue.I mean 2 instance of application was working.